# Swap object values for few properties in javascript

Tags: javascript

current object

```
const obj = {
  k1: v1,
  k2: v2,
  x1: v3,
  x2: v4,
  y: {
    z1: v5,
    z2: v6
  }
}
```

expected object

```
const obj = {
  k1: v2,
  k2: v1,
  x1: v4,
  x2: v3,
  y: {
    z1: v6,
    z2: v5
  }
}
```

Have tried individual swap method for each key and also tried below object assign way

```js
const obj = {
  k1: 'v1',
  k2: 'v2',
  x1: 'v3',
  x2: 'v4',
  y: {
    z1: 'v5',
    z2: 'v6'
  }
}
Object.assign(obj, {
  k1: obj.k2,
  k2: obj.k1,
  x1: obj.x2,
  x2: obj.x1,
  y: {
    z1: obj.y.z2,
    z2: obj.y.z1,
  }
});

Object.keys(obj).forEach(
  (k) =>
    obj[k] === null ||
    (obj[k] === undefined && delete obj[k])
);

console.log(obj)
```

for some cases once object assign is executed undefined will come for x1 or x2 key because v3 or v4 are not mandatory. so after converting trying to remove the undefined keys from object

Expecting a optimized and better solution for it

Answer (score 0):

Your solution was accession undefined keys from `obj` such as `obj.k4` and `obj.k3` also they were assigning to wrong keys aswell `k3` and `k4`.

**Your Corrected Solution**

```js
const obj = {
  k1: 'v1',
  k2: 'v2',
  x1: 'v3',
  x2: 'v4',
  y: {
    z1: 'v5',
    z2: 'v6'
  }
};
Object.assign(obj, {
  k1: obj.k2,
  k2: obj.k1,
  x1: obj.x2,
  x2: obj.x1,
  y: {
    z1: obj.y.z2,
    z2: obj.y.z1,
  }
});
console.log(obj);
```

You can also make use of spread operator for achieving the same.

```js
let obj = {
  k1: 'v1',
  k2: 'v2',
  x1: 'v3',
  x2: 'v4',
  y: {
    z1: 'v5',
    z2: 'v6'
  }
};
obj = {...obj, ...{
  k1: obj.k2,
  k2: obj.k1,
  x1: obj.x2,
  x2: obj.x1,
  y: {
    z1: obj.y.z2,
    z2: obj.y.z1,
  }
}}
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Have tried this way and it is working. expecting a better solution if any other way we can do, will use this way instead

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method to remove the undefined:

```js
const clean = o => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o))
  
const obj = {
  k1: 'v1',
  k2: 'v2',
  x1: 'v3',
  x2: 'v4',
  y: {
    z1: 'v5',
    z2: 'v6',
  },
}

Object.assign(obj, {
  k1: obj.k2,
  k2: obj.k1,
  k3: obj.k4,
  k4: obj.k3,
  y: {
    z1: obj.v6,
    z2: obj.v5,
  },
})

console.log('obj:', obj)
console.log('clean object:', clean(obj))
```